# How can a write a long string store into a csv file without converting the string into a list?

Tags: python, csv

See the code below. I want to save the slash_null_sig string into new_passwords.csv file
[image]

Comment: It seems you are trying to solve Codecademy's tutorial "Hacking the Fender". Please note that there is an excellent walkthrough about this on Codecademy's youtube Channel.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
new_passwords_obj.write(slash_null_sig)
```

and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[new_passwords_obj.write(slash_null_sig)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cIBI.png)